# How to make definitions affect global scope in rails-webpacker-managed js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm converting a rails 5.1 app from sprockets-js to webpacker-js.

In `app/assets/javascripts/libfigure/` there was a directory of about 6 js files that  depend on each other. What I mean by that is earlier files define functions, like so:

```
function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}
```

then later files call these functions:

```
foo();
```

This code does not use  modules. There is not a single call to 'import' or 'export' anywhere in any of these files. They were written for a JS-5 environment.

Now I'm porting to webpacker, and I can't find any switch that says: "yeah, just define all these symbols in the global namespace, I'll take the consequences.". So now I'm writing them all as modules, and figuring out which functions are actually exported by just waiting for "compiler" errors. It's a long process, and not the thing I want to worry about at the moment.

Does anyone know a way to make webpacker let me evaluate all these files in the global scope, or really anything better than what I'm doing right now, which is laboriously rewriting like this:

```
  export const foo = () => { console.log('foo'); );
```

```
  import { foo } from './foo.js'
  foo();
```

Comment: What about creating a single js file in packs folder where you `require` all your files?

Comment: @coorasse are you drawing a distinction between `require` and `import` here? I ask because I am already `import`ing all my files there.

Comment: Its complicated @see https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2019/08/01/dealing-with-legacy-and-externally-loaded-code-in-webpacker/